# Update module jar with module version but no main class

Tags: java, maven, jar, java-platform-module-system

Currently, the maven-jar-plugin does not support setting the main class or the module version (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-238). So the only way is updating the generated jar with the jar tool provided by the JDK.

jar --update --main-class com.sample.Main --module-version 1.0 --file mymodule.jar

This works just fine for a module with a main class. But when I wanted to update a library module with no main class but a module version, I tried this:

jar --update --module-version 1.0 --file mymodule.jar

This produces an error message, that either a main class, a manifest or some files are required. Why can't I update a jar just with a module version? Am I missing a point here?

A sample project can be found here: https://github.com/future2r/jigsaw

Comment: I think we have a bug in the jar tool, see: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210454

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for sharing the link!